# If "a:domain.com" is used, would it include emails sent from *@subdomain.domain.com address?

Tags: email, dns, syntax, spf

Supposedly I have `example.com` domain and would like it to allow mails sent from `subdomain.domain.com`.

If the spf record should verify emails sent from *@subdomain.domain.com address (or mailed-by: subdomain.domain.com), would `"v=spf1 a:domain.com ~all"` allow the subdomain of domain.com too or only the domain.com?

I'm not sure if my question makes any sense, but would be glad to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPF works somewhat differently than you're trying to describe.

---

SPF records don't allow domains; they allow **mail servers.** When you put `a:domain.com` in an SPF record, that only means "accept mail **from the IP address** found at `domain.com/A`". If that actually points to your outgoing SMTP server, good. (In larger sites that wouldn't be the case.)

`include:domain.com` works in a similar way: instead of 'A' records, it does 'TXT' record lookups and imports domain.com's SPF policy. But that still boils down to "accept mail from those IP addresses that domain.com's SPF would have accepted".

So to answer the question, `a:` or `include:` won't include subdomains. That wouldn't make sense, and is actually impossible: there's no way for validators to know that a given IP address exists *somewhere*  inside the domain.

---

SPF records *themselves* are found by looking up the sender's domain in DNS.  For example, if the message has `root@subdomain.example.com` as its Envelope-From address, then SPF validators will search for a TXT record at `subdomain.example.com` – but they *will not* search the parent domain.

In other words, SPF policy specified at `domain.com` *does not* apply to messages sent by `*@subdomain.example.com`. If you want both domains to be protected by SPF, you should either copy or 'include' the policy explicitly, or use the 'redirect=' modifier.

Comment: You are right, it was a bit different in my head. This seems like a well-written complete answer (and more!) so marking this as answered. Useful as now I see how it works. In my example, _example.com_ said "check _domain.com_ for the range of IPs". _subdomain.domain.com_ says the same thing, "check _domain.com_ for the range of IPs". And there it was, the SPF/TXT record for with the IP ranges at _domain.com_

Comment: I also mixed "a:" with "include:" in my question. So the _example.com_ actually had `"v=spf1 include:domain.com ~all"`, not `"v=spf1 a:domain.com ~all"`

Comment: The answer to that isn't very different at all -- instead of taking IP addresses from 'A' records, it takes _additional SPF policies_ from 'TXT' records at `domain.com`, but the logic is still the same and subdomains are not included.